# macvim shell (:sh) only displays character codes / escape sequences

Tags: shell, vim, zsh, macvim

Just compiled MacVim with homebrew. Here's what it looks like when I :sh and then type ls:

http://cloud.jtmkrueger.com/image/2N0S0T3k3l1J

As you can see, it's just character codes.

**UPDATE**

I run oh-my-zsh

Tried installing the plugin named here:

http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/ANSI-colors-td1219411.html

Didn't seem to help

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Upon removing my [zsh syntax highlighting plugin](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/) It seems to work ok.  Is there a way to turn off zsh plugins when using oh-my-zsh only when it's a vim 'dumb terminal'?

Comment: What is the result of `:echo &term`?

Comment: Well there's your problem. Try the conque plugin.

Comment: @thatmiddleway, Hi! I am using ZSH but I don't have that plugin enabled. When you say it's working for you do you mean the colors are displayed correctly? I am trying to get this working with the MacVIM plugin Vroom, so to be able to run Rspec from within MacVIM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `:sh` in GVim or MacVim, you don't get a real terminal emulator.

It's "dumb" and there's **no** way to make it understand those escape sequences. You better get used to it or ask (with convincing arguments and a ready-made patch) on the vim-dev mailing list.

Comment: I think I'm going to go change my votes at vim.org ;)
Is there a way to have my emulator avoid/skip the escape sequences as @honk suggests below? I tried what he said and it didn't work.

Comment: **There's no way to display colors when doing `:sh` in MacVim or GVim**. The internal pseudo terminal emulator doesn't support colors at all and that's unlikely to change anytime soon. In the terminal, `:sh` suspends Vim and launchs a new shell in the same terminal so colors are respected. Also, what votes are you talking about?

Comment: [Conque Shell](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) is a plugin that emulates a shell inside a Vim buffer. Maybe it will work for you.

Comment: if you donate at least 10 euros at vim.org, you can vote on future feature development.

Comment: That's funny. I can't think of any feature I'd like to be added to Vim.

Comment: That's not an issue at all from my point of view. If I want a terminal I use a terminal. If I need to check out the file structure of the current project I use `:Hex`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the [ConqueTerm plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) which does its best to interpret ANSI sequences, even inside MacVim.

Comment: My hope is to not have a plugin fix something that is 'included' basic functionality.

Comment: Well you *did* mention installing a plugin to fix your problem. Moreover, what you consider "included" is terminal-dependent stuff, and thus is not given in gvim or MacVim. Just use iTerm2 and vim inside it if you need such functionality without plugins...

Comment: That's what I normally do. I'm trying to get the same functionality out of macvim though.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the reference, `:h guioptions` [now support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/VcyMs-s1l-M) the following flag:

```
  '!'   External commands are executed in a terminal window.  Without
        this flag the MS-Windows GUI will open a console window to
        execute the command.  The Unix GUI will simulate a dumb
        terminal to list the command output.
        The terminal window will be positioned at the bottom, and grow
        upwards as needed.
```

Set `:set go+=!`, run `:sh`, and be surprised :).

Comment: This got me pretty close. The only thing that isn't working is custom devicon fonts.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is actually not just character codes, but your usual shell prompt which contains color codes. You can probably disable it by redefining `PS1` or remove your modified definition in `~/.bashrc`.

If you would like to use a color prompt on the command line, but not in MacVim you can fix this in `~/.bashrc` by setting PS1 differently when inside vim (from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/change-ps1-when-shing-in-vim-808913/))

```
if [ $VIM ]; then
        export PS1='\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Comment: I use zsh with oh-my-zsh.  I don't even have a .bashrc

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with my zsh text highlighting plugin now...

Comment: I end up with just adding

```
if [ ! $TERM = dumb ]; then
    source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
fi
```

in my `.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, instead of ls, type `command ls`; it shouldn't show the escapes codes.
If it works you can simple create a new file in a folder in your path, say vls, with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
command ls $@
```

after that `chmod +x vls` and again, if it is in your path, you should be able to use that from vim.